# Laravel route resolve custom data type

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-routing, laravel-service-container

I have the following routes in `routes/api.php`:

```
Route::get('items/{item}', function(Guid $item) {...});
Route::get('users/{user}', function(Guid $user) {...});
```

Since `Guid` is a custom type, how can I resolve that via *dependency injection*? As shown, the route parameter `{item}` differs from the callback parameter type-hint:`Guid` so it can not be automatically resolved.

---

That's what I've tried in *`app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`*:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(Guid::class, function(Application $app, array $params) {
            return Guid::fromString($params[0]);
        });
    }
}
```

I'd expect `$params` to be something like this: `[ 'item' => 'guid' ]` -- but it is: `[]`.

Comment: In how far does `{item}`  differ from `Guid $item`? That the first is a string (sub-string of an URL-.Path) and the second is not a string at all? How does Laravel in general map URL-Path sub-strings to _any_ PHP object type according to your understanding? Or do you see the difference elsewhere?

Comment: The item route parameter is a guid string while Guid is a wrapper object that has some utility methods like validation. Laravel normally maps to models. But since I had to implement the model itself (it's not a database model like Laravel's model), I thought, it'd be easier to solve it this way than implementing the whole `URLRoutable` contract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [*explicit binding* <sup>*Laravel Routing*</sup>](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#explicit-binding):

in *`RouteServiceProvider::boot()`*:

```
public function boot()
{
    Route::model('item', Guid $item);
    Route::model('user', Guid $user);
}
```

If `Guid` is *not* a model use a *Closure* to map onto the string:

```
Route::bind('user', function ($value) {
   return Guid::fromString($value);
});
```

---

**UPDATED**

And I found another way, much better - implement [*UrlRoutable* contract <sup>*Lavaravel API*</sup>](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Routing/UrlRoutable.html):

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\UrlRoutable;

class Guid implements UrlRoutable
{
    private string $guid;

    public function setGuid(string $guid)
    {
        $this->guid = $guid;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getGuid(): string
    {
        return $this->guid;
    }

    public static function fromString(string $guid): self
    {
        //you cannot set props from constructor in this case
        //because binder make new object of this class
        //or you can resolve constructor depts with "give" construction in ServiceProvider
        return (new self)->setGuid($guid);
    }
    public function getRouteKey()
    {
        return $this->guid;
    }

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'guid';
    }

    public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null)
    {
        //for using another "fields" check documentation
        //and maybe another resolving logic
        return self::fromString($value);
    }

    public function resolveChildRouteBinding($childType, $value, $field)
    {
        //or maybe you have relations
        return null;
    }
}
```

And, with this, you can use routes like you want as `Guid` now implements `UrlRoutable` and can turn `{item}` (or whatever) URL-path sub-string markers into **Guid**s per *dependency injection* (by the type-hint as you asked for it):

```
Route::get('items/{item}', function(Guid $item) {
   return $item->getGuid();
});
```

> BTW: **NEVER EVER** use closures in routes as you cannot cache closure routes - and routes are good to be optimized, and caching helps with that in Laravel routing.

Comment: But `Guid` is not a model. It's just a custom compound type. The closure is for presentation purposes only - thanks for the hint!

Comment: Updated for non model

Comment: Thanks, but in this case, every time, I want to use a guid, the route param has to be named user or I have to manually create a binding for each parameter, right?

Comment: I think, the best way is to bind Guid to “guid” and use /users/{guid}, items/{guid}

Comment: Not perfect but probably the best we can get. Thank you!

Comment: @shaedrich I'm updating the answer, pls check :)

Comment: @Maksim: Your note about closures in routing (which sounds fair), is it a warning because you have a closure in the example and or is it that the example show how the closure is prevented? Just asking, because as giving the warning sounds legit, it's kind of incomplete without giving a hint how a closure can be prevented (at least on the level of the warning note).

Comment: @hakre A closure can be prevented by using a controller tuple (`[ YourController::class, 'yourMethod' ]`) or string (`YourController::yourMethod'`) instead

Answer (score 1):

simple helper to utilize route binding callback.

```
if (!function_exists('resolve_bind')) {
    function resolve_bind(string $key, mixed $value) {
        return call_user_func(Route::getBindingCallback($key), $value);
    }
}
```

usage

```
resolve_bind('key', 'value');
```